# Not able to see images inside scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have 2 `scrollviews` and 1 `imageview`.

now Inside Main `scrollview` I have another `scrollview` and in this `scrollview` I have image.

so, my Main `Scrollview` named "`ScrollView`" and sub `scrollview` named "`scrView`"

now I am able to add "`scrView`" inside "`ScrollView`" but I can not see my image inside "`scrView`"

My coding is as follows:

```
int numberOfPages = 10;
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * numberOfPages, scrollView.bounds.size.height)];

    CGRect pageFrame;
    CGRect imageFrame;
    UIImageView *imageView;

    for(int i=0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        pageFrame = CGRectMake(i * scrollView.bounds.size.width+50, 0.0f, scrollView.bounds.size.width-100, scrollView.bounds.size.height);
        UIScrollView *scrView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        imageFrame = CGRectMake(i * scrView.bounds.size.width, 0.0f, scrView.bounds.size.width, scrView.bounds.size.height);
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]];
                    [scrView setFrame:pageFrame];
        [imageView setFrame:imageFrame];
        [scrView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [scrollView addSubview:scrView];
        [scrView addSubview:imageView];

        [imageView release];
    }
```

If you look at the code I have added `imageView` as a `subView` of `scrView` but I am not able to see image in simulator.

what is the problem?

share your ideas with me.

thanks...

Comment: is the second scrollView is added to the first scroll ?

Comment: First check the IBOutlet for all ie for main scroll view, sub scroll view and image view.

Comment: try adding this line first `[scrView addSubview:imageView];` then `[scrollView addSubview:scrView];`

Comment: first add the imageview to sub scroll view and then add the sub scroll view to main scroll view ie change the order of last two lines (neglecting the release line)

Comment: @PratyushaTerli: I have done that change but there is no change in result

Comment: set content size for scrView

Comment: @PratyushaTerli I have manually inserted it like [scrView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(160, 100)]; but no change in result

Comment: try my answer working for me.hope works for you as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working try this code.**Problem was with your imageview frame**

```
int numberOfPages = 10;
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * numberOfPages, scrollView.bounds.size.height)];

CGRect pageFrame;
CGRect imageFrame;
UIImageView *imageView;

for(int i=0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
{
    pageFrame = CGRectMake(i * scrollView.bounds.size.width+50, 0.0f, scrollView.bounds.size.width-100, scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    UIScrollView *scrView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pageFrame];
    imageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0f, scrView.bounds.size.width, scrView.bounds.size.height);

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"];

   // [scrView setFrame:pageFrame];

    [scrView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [scrView addSubview:imageView];
    [scrollView addSubview:scrView];


    [imageView release];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your precious help it is working now. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Set a **background** color to your **imageView** too.. Then **Log** and check the scrView & imageFrame **frames**. Also use **`bringSubviewToFront:`** property.

```
for(int i=0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        UIScrollView *scrView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        [scrView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
        pageFrame = CGRectMake(i * scrollView.bounds.size.width+50, 0.0f, scrollView.bounds.size.width-100, scrollView.bounds.size.height);

        imageFrame = CGRectMake(i * scrView.bounds.size.width, 0.0f, scrView.bounds.size.width, scrView.bounds.size.height);
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]];
                    [scrView setFrame:pageFrame];
        [imageView setFrame:imageFrame];
        [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]
        [scrView addSubview:imageView];
        [scrView bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
        [imageView release];

        [scrollView addSubview:scrView];
        [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:scrView];
    }
```

Comment: thanks but I want 10 different sub scrollviews inside a single scrollview

Answer (score 0):

just try to set like this from your code mate..

```
[scrView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[scrView addSubview:imageView]; /// first add imageview and then scrview (screen view) to scrollview
[scrollView addSubview:scrView];
```

Comment: I have already implemented these lines to my code but no change in the result.